# Local variables in remote script

Tags: powershell, arguments, invoke-command

I've created a script to cycle through a spreadsheet with two columns. The problem I'm running into is that the local variables are not working when I run `invoke-command`.  I've added the `-ArgumentList` parameter but I'm still getting an error about `$null` arguments.  Anyone know what I'm doing wrong here?

```powershell
foreach ($list in (Import-Csv C:\Users\joerod\Desktop\remove_users.csv)) {
    Write-Output "Connecting to $($list.computer)..."
    $myses = New-PSSession -ComputerName $list.computer
    Invoke-Command -Session $myses -ScriptBlock {
        Write-Output "Searching for software..."
        Write-Output $list.user

        $find_java = gwmi Win32_Product -Filter "Name LIKE '%Java'" | select -ExpandProperty IdentifyingNumber
        if ($find_java -ne $null) {
            Write-Output "Software found... Uninstalling..."
            foreach ($i in $find_mktx) {
                msiexec.exe /x $i /qn /passive /l*v! c:\uninst.log 
            }
            Write-Output "Adding $($list.user) to security group"
            $group = "CN=Java_removed,OU=Groups,OU=Resources,DC=Contoso,DC=LOCAL"
            Add-ADGroupMember $group -Identity $list.user
        }
        else {
            Write-Output "Could not find Java software installed"
        } 
    } -ArgumentList $list
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is your trying to pass an arguement list into your `else`. It's alot easier to see if you format your code properly.

```
foreach($list in (Import-Csv C:\Users\joerod\Desktop\remove_users.csv)){
    Write-Output "Connecting to $($list.computer)..."
    $myses = New-PSSession -ComputerName $list.computer
    Invoke-Command -Session $myses -ScriptBlock {
    Param($list)
        Write-Output "Searching for software..."
        Write-Output $list.user

        $find_java = gwmi win32_product -filter "Name LIKE '%Java'" | select -ExpandProperty     IdentifyingNumber
        if($find_java -ne $null){
            Write-Output "Software found... Uninstalling..."
            foreach($i in $find_mktx){
                msiexec.exe /x $i /qn /passive /l*v! c:\uninst.log 
            }
            Write-Output "Adding $($list.user) to security group"
            $group = "CN=Java_removed,OU=Groups,OU=Resources,DC=Contoso,DC=LOCAL"
            Add-ADGroupMember $group -Identity $list.user
        }
        else{
            Write-Output "Could not find Java software installed"
        } 
    } -ArgumentList $list

}
```

Comment: That was my mistake when I copied the script over, the `-ArgumentList $list` is in the correct place and still same error

Comment: @JoeRod You were also missing the `Param($list)` after your `invoke-command`... was that a copy mistake as well?

Comment: Ah yes the Param that I was missing, thanks dude.  And thanks for not being condescending.